# Calling R script from Python

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

I wrote script in Python. I would like to plot some graphs using R.

I get an error When I run following code

```
import sys
import argparse
import os
import subprocess
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=messg, prog='parser.py', 
    usage='%(prog)s -m [file.txt]')
parser.add_argument('-m', required=True, help='file.txt', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('-o', required=True, help='Save output to file', type=argparse.FileType('w'))

args = parser.parse_args()

for ln in args.m:
    prefix, proteins = ln.rstrip().split(':')
    proteins = proteins.split()
    args.o.write('%s\t' % prefix,)
args.o.write('\n')

subprocess.call("Rscript script.r"+args.o, shell=True)
```

I get following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 18, in <module>
    subprocess.call("Rscript script.r"+args.o, shell=True)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'file' objects
```

But it works when I run it from command line

```
Rscript script.r file.txt
```

Can anyone point where am i making mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you aware of [RPy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpy2) ?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Its great. But I stuck at reading table in r. I would like to use output file from above script into R. I have added code below. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`type=argparse.FileType('w'))` creates a file object so you are trying to concatenate the string to the file object, if you want the output written to a file you can pass the file object to `subprocess` and have it write the stdout directly to the file.

```
subprocess.check_call(["Rscript script.r"],stdout=args.o)
```

`

Comment: I would like to write output to file first and then pass the file to Rscript.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in @padraic-cunningham 's answer, the parameter is a file object. Use its path:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = importr('utils')

# close the file (in case we are on Windows)
args.m.close()
tbl = base.read_table(args.m.name,sep='\t')
grdevices=importr('grDevices')
grdevices.png(file="Plot.png", width=512, height=512)
r.plot(tbl[1], tbl[2], xlab= "x", ylab= "y")
grdevices.dev_off()
```